# How to use ZendOpCache for Doctrine2 cache?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, opcache

I have installed PHP 5.5.1 in my development environment, and also have config Zend OpCache as Cache provider. Everything is working on the server with the new version and settings, but inside my symfony 2 project I have the Doctine2 cache to store some "static" data (countries, languages, etc) and it not works with Opcache.

Until today, I was using the [Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache](http://www.igestis.org/api/class-Doctrine.Common.Cache.ApcCache.html) class to work with the cache of Doctrine2 using APC, but seems that does not exists a class to work with OpCache.

This is my config.yml for APC cache:

```
# Services
services:
    cache:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache
```

Now, with OpCache I have tried to use [ZendDataCache](http://www.igestis.org/api/namespace-Doctrine.Common.Cache.html) to deal with cache system, but does not work:

```
# Services
services:
    cache:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ZendDataCache
```

I get this error, so I assume that ZendDataCache class is not for OpCache:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\zend_shm_cache_fetch() in /var/www/meediam/src/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ZendDataCache.php line 38

Finally I have configured the [ArrayCache](http://www.igestis.org/api/class-Doctrine.Common.Cache.ArrayCache.html), and it works, but without cache system behind.

So the question is, 
**Anyone know how to use Zend OpCache with Doctrine 2 Cache?**

*PS: I am using Symfony 2.3.2*

Comment: PHP's OpCache is a simple opcode cache. In order to store data in cache you will need something like: [APCu](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu).

Comment: Perfect. It works using APCu User Cache. (if you want, you could answer the question in a new reply to mark it as resolved)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Adding my comment as an answer.*

PHP's OpCache is not a full blown cache as APC It is a simply opcode cache. If you want to store custom data just like you would with the old APC you can use [Joe Watkins'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658631/joe-watkins) APCu: https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu.

There is also [yac](https://github.com/laruence/yac) and memcache.

Answer (score -2):

You can actually use OpCache indirectly via PhpFileCache