# Using opcache on PHP 5.6 with Symfony 2.5.*

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.5

We would like to 'migrate' our project to use opcache, instead of apc. How can we do this?

On our VPS, we have php 5.6 installed with `opcache.enable => On`, however, our assets won't load and Doctrine shows several errors in the logfile. (Because Doctrine is still trying to call ApcCache)

> 2015/02/16 15:22:21 [error] 22231#0: *29515 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch() in *snip_path*/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php on line 40" while reading response header from upstream, client: *snip_ip*, server: *snip_server*, request: "GET /app_dev.php/js/57b7149_part_1_templates_2.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php_fpm_cynex.sock:", host: "*snip_host*", referrer: "*snip_referer*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using apc with doctine orm, please check app/config/config.yml

```
doctrine:
   orm:
      ...
      metadata_cache_driver: apc
      ...
```

[Refer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers)

If you are using it, you need to disbale it, clear cache and try it.

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine is trying to use APC cache driver wich is probably turned off in your VPS.

Comment: We can read the error, too. Maybe the question wasn't clear: How do we migrate a Symfony2.5 project away from using APC?

Comment: Do you really need it? Opcache is php accelerator, while APC is accelerator AND key value storage. You can use both (opcache for php boost and APC for caching variables)

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with Doctrine, the issue seems to be that Doctrine is behaving like APC is installed, which it clearly isn't

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch()

Apparently Doctrine wants to control Opcache in ways [it's not designed to perform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18042566/2370483)

> PHP's OpCache is not a full blown cache as APC It is a simply opcode cache.